# how can i find the inverse transformation of the following transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

if $ T: P_2 \to P_2$ defined by $T(\alpha_0 +\alpha_1 x+\alpha_2 x^2)=(\alpha_0 +\alpha_1)+(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2)x +(\alpha_0+\alpha_1+3\alpha_2)x^2$

then how shall I find the inverse $T^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $T^{-1}(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$, such that $T(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2$.

Then you have the following:

$\begin{array}[t]{l}
(c_0+c_1)+(c_1+2c_2)\cdot x + (c_0+c_1+3c_2)\cdot x^2=b_0+b_1\cdot x+b_2\cdot x^2
\end{array}$

You need to solve the $3\times 3  $ linear system with variables $c_0,c_1,c_2$ $(b_0,b_1,b_2$ are considered known quantities).

$\begin{array}[t]{l}
c_0+c_1=b_0\\
c_1+2c_2=b_1\\
c_0+c_1+3c_2=b_2
\end{array}$